# Add facebook Comment Box social plugin in my iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

i want to add facebook Comment Box in my iphone app. is it possible ? if it possible  please provide me any idea.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible using a `UIWebView`. If you don't know how to do that, have a look in the [Apple Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).